# Using OR in SUMIF Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a curious question about using the "OR" in an excel SUMIF.

Basically, in a

```
SUMIF(A:A,"Cat" OR "Dog", C1:C10)
```

How can I use the OR function in an excel SUMIF function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the different OR parameters into curly brackets and enclose the whole Sumif in a SUM function, because Sumif will return an array of values that need to be summed up.

Also, the two ranges need to be the same size.

```
=SUM(SUMIF(A1:A10,{"cat","dog"}, C1:C10))
```

Comment: Thank you! I found another solution too. You can use Wildcard so I used "X*"  and it worked. It grabbed the values for everything containing X.

Comment: I had changed my data to protect its integrity. I had 2 products starting with X and another with X-100. So I used SUMIFS and used "X*". It worked.